# Why is there no "Functor" trait in Scala?

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming, functor

In Scala, the generic classes such as `Future`, `Option` and `List` all have methods `map` and `flatMap`. As I understand, all of them are like [Functors](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functor) in Haskell.

I was just wondering why there isn't a trait (interface) called Functor in Scala..

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: Because Scala isn't a research language? Haskell is a less general/practical-use language than Scala, one might say.

Comment: @AJFarmar, since `Functor` is of immense practical value, I'm not sure how that answers it. That would better express why it doesn't have, say, a `Category` trait.

Comment: @dfeuer But the word itself is derived from category theory, which I wouldn't expect to appear in Scala or any other mainstream language. Maybe it's under a different name?

Comment: There is a [FilterMonadic](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.generic.FilterMonadic)
 trait which contains both `.map` and `.flatMap` methods. It does however also contains the `.foreach` method as well as the `.withFilter` method. However I don't know why it was named this way, nor why `.withFilter` was put here together with `.map` and `.flatMap`.

Comment: @AJFarmar, oh, well, the name is a whole different story. I once heard a Haskell researcher say `Functor` should've been called `Mappable`.

Comment: This isn't a good question for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How would such trait look like? Remember, functor is determined by an `fmap` function which lifts a regular function to a function acting on "functorial" values (or, alternatively, applies a regular function to functor contents). The closest I can think of is

```
trait Functor[T] {
  type Self[U] <: Functor[U]
  def fmap[U](f: T => U): Self[U]
}
```

Such definition is not really useful and relatively complex. Traits do not have necessary flexibility for abstracting higher-kinded concepts like functors.

However, Scala does have type classes, that is, it is possible to use traits and implicit parameters in a clever way to implement the type class pattern:

```
trait Functor[F[_]] {
  def fmap[T, U](f: T => U)(v: F[T]): F[U]
}

implicit object OptionFunctor extends Functor[Option] {
  def fmap[T, U](f: T => U)(v: Option[T]): Option[U] = v match {
    case Some(r) => Some(f(r))
    case None => None
  }
}

def doSomething[F[_]: Functor](f1: F[Int], f2: F[String]): F[Long] = ???  // whatever
// equivalent to:
// doSomething :: Functor f => f Int -> f String -> f Long
// in Haskell
```

And that's precisely what [scalaz](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/nightly/index.html#scalaz.Functor) provides.

As for why this is not present in the standard library - I don't know. Maybe the type class pattern was not discovered immediately, and the library had already been formed at that moment. Maybe it's just because these are somewhat advanced concepts which don't really belong to the standard library. Maybe something else.

Comment: "I don't know" - good answer!

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov, I believe I've answered the original question (why there is no functor *trait* in stdlib) - it's just it is not that useful and convenient. "I don't know" bit was about type classes.

Comment: This is factually incorrect. Scala's std lib does have some typeclasses: Numeric (== Haskell's Num), Integral (== Integral), Fractional (== Fractional), Ordering (== Ord), Equiv (== Eq).

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov, again, I didn't mean *all* type classes. I meant categorical type classes, like functor, monad, etc. Please don't find superfluous meaning in what I'm saying.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev - as to why Scala doesn't provide categorical typeclasses in the standard library, I would guess because they cordon off higher-kinded types as an explicitly optional language feature and they don't want to use optional features in the standard library.

Comment: @Yawar, well, higher-kinded types are exactly as optional as the collections library is. The collections library uses higher-kinded types, for example [`GenTraversableTemplate`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.generic.GenericTraversableTemplate). or [`GenericCompanion`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.generic.GenericCompanion).

Answer (score 5):

I think the assumption is that anyone interested in using Functor/Applicative/Monad/etc. is better served by using Scalaz. Not being in the standard library means it's more free to evolve, isn't tied to the Scala release schedule, etc. [Just look at how long it took to make `Monad` extend `Applicative` in GHC!](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal)